# I've got a simple error in my ContextMenu, can someone please sort it out?

Tags: java, android, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to get a context menu working for a list of items as you can see below, but I'm not sure how to link when an item is clicked to the list names. The line with >>>>> is the one which I think I've got wrong. Can someone please just have a look at what I've done wrong?
Here's my Main_Acitivty:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
private SoundAdapter mAdapter = null;
static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
//create a simple list
mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();
Sound s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Anjels");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.anjels);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Aggro");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.aggro);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Axo");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.axo);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Basix");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.basix);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Bender");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.bender);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Blimp");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.blimp);
mSounds.add(s);
mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
mp.start();

}@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    >>>>>>String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(mSounds);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.setasnotification:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Applying " + getResources().getString(R.string.setas) +
                      " context menu option for " + names[(int)info.id],
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

CHange `String[] names = getResources().getString(R.array.?????);`

to `String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.?????);`

You can refer to [android docs on String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Example of string array resource:

```
XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

To access array of planets:

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: Added example. You can edit your strings.xml as per the example

Comment: But all my items are in the main thread. What should I do in that case?